# Adjective for unfair or ill-intentioned question

Tags: single-word-requests

What adjective could describe a question that is designed to make the answerer look like a fool? Or asked out of the intention to make the answerer look like a fool?

"Hard" question does not strongly enough convey maliciousness of the asker.

Comment: Try [trick question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trick-question).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey a trick question does not have connotations of being malicious

Comment: A trick question can be malicious if the intent is to make the other person look foolish.

Comment: What's wrong with "unfair", or "ill-intentioned"?

Comment: Not an adjective but you could say something along lines of:  *that question was like a torpedo*. Or *he torpedoed the speaker by asking ______.*

Answer (score 1):

The question is a particular type of *leading* question.

> A leading question is a question which subtly prompts the respondent to answer in a particular way. Leading questions are generally undesirable as they result in false or slanted information.
>
> [Media College](https://www.mediacollege.com/journalism/interviews/leading-questions.html)

Or, in this case, lead the answerer to foolish or self-contradictory statements.

Comment: Very hypernymic. I take it you haven't found a more appropriate definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes you are correct. It is as close as I can get "coming down from above", as you might say. A more focused word eludes me.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an *insidious* question

> **insidious**
>
> 2a. awaiting a chance to entrap : TREACHEROUS

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insidious)

The word is used so often to describe direct causation of harm that it will connote the maliciousness you want it to.

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/insidious) defines it as

> 1. intended to entrap or beguile
> 2. stealthily treacherous or deceitful
> 3. operating or proceeding in an inconspicuous or seemingly harmless way but actually with grave effect